# Find $x$ in $\log x^2 = (\log x)^2$

Tags: logarithms

Find $x$ in  $\log  x^2 = (\log x)^2$.

I couldn't find x.

Comment: What are those stars?

Comment: They are supposed to italisize

Comment: Hint: use $\log(x^2) = 2\log x$ for positive $x$.

Comment: no, its fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that $$\log x^2=2\log x$$ for all $x>0.$ Now use the substitution $u=\log x$ to get $$2u=u^2.$$ Solve for $u,$ then solve for $x.$

Comment: thanks, your way helped me understand it a bit better.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 4):

$$\log x^2 = (\log x)^2
\\2\log x = (\log x)^2
\\ \log x(\log x-2)=0
\\ \log x=0 \to x=1
\\ \log x=2 \to x=10^2$$

Comment: thanks, but the other person's way was a bit more clear.

Comment: Never mind, as always if you face any problem just let me know